# Drop down menu in `<nav>` and `<center>` not centered

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

Thanks to the great people on here, I have fixed one issue of my drop down menu. Now I have another little problem. My drop down menu in my nav bar isn’t centered. It’s supposed to be directly under “Works” but it is moved to the left.

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "mrs-eaves";
}

.dropbtn {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: "mrs-eaves";
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover,
.dropbtn:hover,
.dropdown:hover,
.dropdown-content a:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: rgb(247, 219, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <center>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Works
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
      <a href="drawing.html">Drawing</a>
      <a href="animation.html">Animation</a>
      <a href="design.html">Design</a>
    </div>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="links.html">Links</a>
  </center>
</nav>
```

Comment: Where is `myFunction`? Please [edit] your post and make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Note also that `<center>` is an **obsolete** element and should no longer be used. I have no idea why they keep teaching this stuff.

Comment: @metrocode ,check my anwer

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, I have wrapped the `button` and `dropdown-content` with `span` tag with class name as `holder`, and made its `position: relative`. This will ensure that the `dropdown-content` will be positioned wrt to its `span` parent.

Also I have removed the overflow:hidden property on the `nav` tag as the dropdown menu was not visible

And I have added

```
 left: -26px;
 top: 30px;
```

In order to position the menu directly below the `button`

```css
nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "mrs-eaves";
}

.dropbtn {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: "mrs-eaves";
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover,
.dropbtn:hover,
.dropdown:hover,
.dropdown-content a:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: rgb(247, 219, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: block; /*Added for testing purpose*/
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  
   left: -26px;
   top: 30px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.holder{
position:relative;
}

.center{text-align:center;}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="center">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <span class="holder">
    <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Works
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
      <a href="drawing.html">Drawing</a>
      <a href="animation.html">Animation</a>
      <a href="design.html">Design</a>
    </div>
    </span>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="links.html">Links</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```